# I have two recycler view one vertical and other horizantal

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two recyclerView, the first one is horizontal and the second one is vertical. I write two adapters for them apart and they work perfectly but when I scroll the vertical one the horizontal one stuck on top of the page. what I want is that I want when I scroll the page the horizontal one scroll too and is hidden not stuck above the page.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp">
    
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/categoryChipRv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingStart="12dp"
            android:paddingEnd="12dp" />
    
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/videoListRv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingStart="12dp"
            android:paddingEnd="12dp" />
    
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can scroll recyclerview properly by put RecyclerView inside `NestedScrollView` like below. Also add `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` to vertical RecyclerView.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/categoryChipRv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingStart="12dp"
                android:paddingEnd="12dp" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/videoListRv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:paddingStart="12dp"
                android:paddingEnd="12dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: it has an error and said scrollView just want one child.

Comment: @Shahram Zarie now check it.